# Disabling edit of Mapbox GL Draw polygons

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

When creating a polygon using [Mapbox GL Draw](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw) I do not want the polygon to then be editable, clickable etc. After ending the draw event, I'd like to to just appear as finished like below when it's deselected.

Maybe this is embedded in the simple_select config option?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Mapbox Draw plugin provides an interface for writing and hooking in [custom modes](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/docs/MODES.md), where a mode is defined as way to group sets of user interactions into one behavior. [Mapbox Draw Static Mode](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw-static-mode) is a custom mode that displays data stored in Draw but does not let users interact with it, which sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**modes.simple_select.onDrag** function disable the onDrag event.
I give you a small example to can contextualize it.
Inside your @map-init method you should have:

```
const modes = MapboxDraw.modes;
let draw = new MapboxDraw({
    // your mapBoxDraw options
  });

map.on("draw.create", updateArea);

modes.draw_polygon.clickAnywhere = function (state, e) {
//your polygon click restrictions 
}

modes.simple_select.onDrag = function (state, e) {
    //when polygon is deselected onDrag will be false and user not be able to drag it
};

function updateArea(e) {
// your stuff when you're drawing
}
```